# On Poincaré duality and the universal coefficient theorem

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, compact-manifolds

There is a version of Poincaré duality (page 53 of Griffths-Harris) which reads:

> Let $X$ be a closed oriented (connected) $n$-manifold. The intersection pairing $$H_k(X)\otimes H_{n-k}(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$$
>   yields a surjection $H_k(X)\to \mathrm{Hom}(H_{n-k}(X),\mathbb{Z})$,
>   moreover any $x\in H_k(X)$ with $$x\otimes H_{n-k}(X)\mapsto 0$$ is
>   torsion.

This points to the following decomposition: $$H_k(X)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(H_{n-k}(X),\mathbb{Z})\oplus \mathrm{Torsion}(H_k(X)).$$
The universal coefficient theorem gives us $$H^{n-k}(X)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(H_{n-k}(X),\mathbb{Z})\oplus\mathrm{Hom}(H_{n-k-1}(X),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}).$$

Note that an isomorphism between the second summands above would recover the Poincaré duality isomorphism $\phi\colon H_k(X)\cong H^{n-k}(X)$ (but naturality seems an issue to me).

Edit 2: Thanks to the comments, I added a specific question and edited the text accordingly.

**Question**: How can one prove $\mathrm{Torsion}(H_k(X))\cong\mathrm{Hom}(H_{n-k-1}(X),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ by assuming the theorem in blockquote (*not* assuming the map $\phi$)?

Comment: The correct statement is explained in the wikipedia page on Poincaré duality, in its section «Bilinear pairings formulation».

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read that article, and actually that was one of the reasons I started thinking about this. If you know how to relate my question to what's written there in a rigorous way, I'd be happy to read that. Otherwise, I think my question is still not really answered by that paragraph on wikipedia's page (at least I don't see how to formulate a precise relation).

Comment: The isomorphism $\operatorname{Torsion} H_i M \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\operatorname{Torsion} H_{n-i-1} M, \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$, given by the linking form and establishing a duality, is precisely the relation you want.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I guess my point is that the isomorphism you stated is obtained (in the wiki page) through Poincaré duality. Here I am trying to identify the torsion of $H_k(X)$ as linear functionals of the second torsion and thus prove Poincaré duality.